# How to cross out a table cell using pdfHtml and iText 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7, pdfhtml

I'm trying to display a crossed-out table cell.
I've tried dozens of different approaches.
My best solution was using four linear-gradients, one for each corner (because there is no support for transparent backgrounds).
[image]

The issue here is, that I have to specify the height of the table cell, thus when the text in any other cell in the same row has more lines than expected, the cross is no longer from corner to corner.

[image]

I've also tried using a `background-image` with `background-size` set to `100% 100%`.
However, pdfHtml does not support `background-size`.
I've tried multiple workarounds that work in Chrome, but none work in pdfHtml.

Does anybody know a (possible) solution?

Thanks,
--Zuzu_Typ--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pdfHTML eventually utilizes iText's layout mechanism which is quite flexible. You can achieve your end goal by customizing the rendering logic for a cell and plug that implementation into pdfHTML.

First off, custom cell renderer:

```
private static class CustomCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
    public CustomCellRenderer(Cell modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomCellRenderer((Cell) modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawBackground(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.drawBackground(drawContext);
        PdfCanvas canvas = drawContext.getCanvas();
        Rectangle area = getOccupiedAreaBBox();
        canvas.moveTo(area.getLeft(), area.getTop()).lineTo(area.getRight(), area.getBottom());
        canvas.moveTo(area.getLeft(), area.getBottom()).lineTo(area.getRight(), area.getTop());
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

Essentially, we have reused the default implementation and extended it with drawing a line from bottom left corner to the right top one and from the top left one to the bottom right corner.

Now, we need to use the custom renderer for layout objects that are created in pdfHTML. They are created in tag workers, so customizing a tag worker for a table cell:

```
private static class CustomTdTagWorker extends TdTagWorker {
    public CustomTdTagWorker(IElementNode element,
            ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
    }

    @Override
    public IPropertyContainer getElementResult() {
        IPropertyContainer cell = super.getElementResult();
        if (cell instanceof Cell) {
            ((Cell) cell).setNextRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer((Cell) cell));
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

The missing piece is that we need to configure pdfHTML to use our custom tag worker for `<td>` cells and the way to do so it to create a custom tag worker factory:

```
private static class CustomTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (TagConstants.TD.equals(tag.name())) {
            return new CustomTdTagWorker(tag, context);
        }
        return super.getCustomTagWorker(tag, context);
    }
}
```

The only missing piece is to pass the custom tag worker factory to pdfHTML itself and this is done via converter properties:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(inFile, outFile, new ConverterProperties().setTagWorkerFactory(new CustomTagWorkerFactory()));
```

With the code above for the following HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        td, th {
            border: solid 1px;
        }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Another cell 1</td>
    <td>Another cell 2</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <td>
      Footer 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Footer 2
    </td>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the following visual result after converting to PDF:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks @AlexeySubach that seems to be a great solution! The only downside is that now every `<td>` element is crossed out. If I understand correctly, one could specify which ones to cross out by giving them a custom CSS class and using a custom `CssApplierFactory` to find them.

Comment: @Zuzu_Typ yep, either this, or in `CustomTdTagWoker` you can query `element.getStyles()` or `element.getAttributes()` and inspect the CSS style / attribute

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it with svg? Should work without the **background-size** property as well.

```css
.diag {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><path d='M1 0 L0 1 L99 100 L100 99' fill='black' /><path d='M0 99 L99 0 L100 1 L1 100' fill='black' /></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: blue;">
  <div class="diag" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SVGs don't work with pdfHtml if you want to support rotated pages.

Comment: Are you sure the svg won't get rotated together with the page?..

Comment: Yes, I am. In order to get a rotated page, you have to use a trick that involves a custom CssApplierFactory and ```HtmlConverter.convertToElements()```, which you can then use to iterate through the elements and finding one with a specific class.
However, the Elements can't hold SVG data, thus making it impossible to use SVG

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make it clear. I mean pages oriented in landscape orientation, I.e. the text isn't rotated with the page.

Comment: @Zuzu_Typ What about a .png image with the cross in it and no background that is set to 100% width&height of the cell? z-index to make it appear above background

Comment: Other than that you can play with math and Pythagoras to get the line lengths and rotation from width & height of the cell and draw it using either two new rotated divs, or using the before & after to draw them

Comment: Unfortunately, if you put an image inside, there is no way of scaling it to the full height.